# Changing Archive Type from *Generic Xcode Archive* to *Mac App Archive*

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6

I've got a small command line app written in Swift, that I'd now like to archive. Like a number of others before me however, I've come up against the problem of how to change the *Archive Type* from *Generic Xcode Archive* to *Mac App Archive*.

The majority of previous answers addressing this problem suggest setting the *Skips Install* flag to *No* for the target. I've done this, but it made no difference. I've also tried setting the same flag to *No* for the project, but the result remains the same. Some of these answers also make a number of other suggestions, which I've also followed where appropriate, but still the *Archive Type* refuses to yield.

The entire project consists of a single 10-line file, and I've now run out of ideas about what else to fiddle about with.

Comment: Same problem here with xcode7. I tried all the suggestions. Maybe the solution can come if someone (Apple stuff) tell us if there is an xcode log that tells why (based on which parameter) xcode  decided to turn this archive to a generic xcode archive?

Answer (score 2):

The type is determined by the content of the archive. If you have a single .app in your /Products/Applications folder (inside the archive) this will qualify as a Application-Archive. If you have more files in that folder or if its not an .app, you've got a different type (like Generic Xcode Archive)